# Unable to run android application

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

While running my Android Kotlin Application, it is giving me below error.
My build gradle has synced successfully.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Auto-applied by using --scan
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.gradle.enterprise', version: '3.12.3', artifact: 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.12.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.12.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Google
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

App level **build.gradle.kts** -

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id ("kotlin-kapt")
//    id ("kotlin-android-extensions")
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id ("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.daggerlearn"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.daggerlearn"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = false
        viewBinding = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")

    implementation ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.28-alpha")
    kapt ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.28-alpha")

    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha01")
    kapt ("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0-alpha01")

//    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.48")
//    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.48")
//    kapt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.48")
////    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03")
////    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")


    val fragmentVersion = "1.6.2"
    implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentVersion")
    
    val lifecycleVersion = "2.7.0"
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")

    val retrofitVersion = "2.6.0"
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion")
    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:${retrofitVersion}")

    val roomVersion = "2.6.1"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")

}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

**Settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "DaggerLearn"
include(":app")
```

Project level **build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id ("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.50" apply false
}
```

My build.gradle file is sycning successfully but giving issue while running the application.

Comment: Share you project ```build.gradle``` and ```settings.gradle``` and other files

Comment: Shared in the respective post.

Comment: Where is project level ```build.gradle```

Comment: Added project level build.gradle.